# Issue in Drawer layout & Navigation View with navigation(navGraph) while using navigate in NavController

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

Am using Drawer layout & Navigation View with navigation(navGraph), navigation works fine with drawer item. The issue came while I was trying to navigate the fragment on button click by using navigate method **navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_leave_apply)**

I have three items in Drawer are **Home**, **Leave Apply**, **Leave Approval**. When I go to **Leave Apply** from **Home** using **navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_leave_apply)** in button click event and it navigate to **Leave Apply** fragment and it was success, but the **Leave Apply** item is not checked in **Drawer**. 1st image is navigate through **Drawer**, 2nd image is using **navController.navigate**

[image]

After this am not able to navigate to **Home screen** using drawer layout, when I clicked **Home** nothing happened.

[image]

**NavController setup Code**

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);

    assert navHostFragment != null;
    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home_screen, R.id.navigation_leave_apply,
            R.id.navigation_leave_approval)
            .setOpenableLayout(binding.drawerLayout).build();

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

    HeaderNavigationDrawerBinding headerBinding = HeaderNavigationDrawerBinding.bind(binding.navView.getHeaderView(0));


public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);

    assert navHostFragment != null;
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

**On Button Click**

```
navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_leave_apply)
```

**NavGraph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home_screen">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home_screen"
    android:name="com.ntp.view.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_leave_apply"
    android:name="com.ntp.view.leave.employee.LeaveApplyFragment"
    android:label="@string/leave"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_leave_apply" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_leave_approval"
    android:name="com.ntp.view.leave.approval.LeaveApprovalFragment"
    android:label="@string/leave_approval"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_leave_approval" />
</navigation>
```

How to sync **Drawer flow** and **navController.navigate**?